# Google distances using C# - Over-Query-Limit

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to fetch google distances in **gridview RowDataBound** with a **force sleep of 1000ms**,Nothing helping,Am getting correct distance for the first query,ie the first row of the gridview, all others i get 'Over-Query-Limit' for *content* variable ,I want to know three things:

- Is there any solution for this situation.
- Is google limiting queries per day OR
- Is google limiting queries per second  ?

```cs
public int getDistance(string origin, string destination)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int distance = 0;
        string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + origin + "&destination=" + destination + "&sensor=false";
        string requesturl = url;
        string content = fileGetContents(requesturl);
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
        try
        {
            distance = (int)o.SelectToken("routes[0].legs[0].distance.value");
            return distance;
        }
        catch
        {
            return distance;
        }
        return distance;
    }
```

Comment: Just read the official [google maps API licensing page](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)

Comment: @lurkerbelow : It says 2500 per day,but then how come am getting the first query output if 2500 is over ?Also it does not tell anything about per second limitations .

Comment: have you read [geocoding-api-query-over-limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805529/geocoding-api-over-query-limit)? some people do report that they have the same issue as you, there's a workaround provided in that link.

Comment: yes i had tried 1000ms delay,no help,They are even advicing to ditch google,i strongly think there is some other proper workaround.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok,As above 2500 queries per day makes google search a paid service i went for another logic,We can calculate distances without google.com as follows :

```cs
    public decimal calcDistance(decimal latA, decimal longA, decimal latB, decimal longB)
    {

        double theDistance = (Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(latA)) *
                Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(latB)) +
                Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(latA)) *
                Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(latB)) *
                Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(longA - longB)));

        return Convert.ToDecimal((RadiansToDegrees(Math.Acos(theDistance)))) * 69.09M * 1.6093M;
    }

    public double DegreesToRadians(decimal degrees)
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble((Convert.ToDecimal(Math.PI) / 180.0M) * degrees);
    }

    public double RadiansToDegrees(double radians)
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble((180.0M / Convert.ToDecimal(Math.PI)) * Convert.ToDecimal(radians));
    }
```

Comment: But there is difference between the two distances (Google vs Yours): one is actual walking/driving distance by HUMAN and other is AS-CROW-FLIES