# Converting String into Google Coordinates

Tags: php, maps, geocoding

I have a String php variable which contains an adress. Lets say $adress = 'Universitätsring 1, 1010 Wien'.

Is there a way to convert this variable into Google Maps Coordinates and save them in other variables?

And really don't get how to act with Geocoding.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, using the xml provided by geocoding which can take the address as a parameter, based on you can get the lat and long:

```
$adress = 'Universitätsring 1, 1010 Wien';
$adress = urlencode($adress);
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' . $adress . '&sensor=true';
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
  $status = $xml->status;
  if ($status == 'OK') {
      $latitude = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
      $longitude = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
  }
```

If you want it as a json or array you can convert the xml:

```
$adress = 'Universitätsring 1, 1010 Wien';
$adress = urlencode($adress);
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' . $adress . '&sensor=true';
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
  $json = json_encode($xml);
  $array = json_decode($json, true);
  if ($array['status'] == 'OK') {
      $latitude = $array['result']['geometry']['location']['lat'];
      $longitude = $array['result']['geometry']['location']['lng'];
      echo $latitude;
      echo $longitude;
  }
```

Comment: wow nice, thank you. The reason for asking is i have that long js code for my maps plugin which contains i.e.

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.2692714, 12.38580539999998),

.. now i can easily replace the coordinates by $latitude and $longitude.. But i think it aint the way Geocoding is supposed to work, is it? :D

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help.

Comment: @muzzie, that's how it suppose to work if you want to get a location. It's nothing wrong with it. In you case you get the values in PHP and send them to javascript I suppose using AJAX. You could also use just Javascript to get the coordinates from that location, but maybe you had to use PHP because you're receiving that address from the serverside.

Comment: In Javascript you would get the coordinates by address using something like this: `var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
    "address": inputAddress
}, function(results) {
    console.log(results[0].geometry.location); //LatLng
});`

Comment: Exactly (serverside)! Thank you. Perfect answer.

Comment: Hi again :)
For some reason it works perfectly on my own webspace/server but does not work on the remote server where the site has to be launched. Both servers are based on PHP 7.0.

Comment: $xml->status is OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Comment: @muzzie, hi. The Google Geocoding API has a daily limit of 2500 I think, but it also limits the speed with which you can make requests. Put a `sleep(1)` call before or after geocode call and it should work(if not, try increasing it by a couple more seconds). Also I think you should post another question regarding this. Or read these same questions I've found on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805529/geocoding-api-over-query-limit . So either you are sending to many reuests or you are sending them too fast.

Comment: Thank you. i am the only person that knows the website. So it is not really possible that the limit is reached :/ It still does not work with sleep. And on my onw server it works perfectly. Thanks anyway for your great help!!

Comment: @muzzie, you can also try and change your API key. That should definitely solve your problem. As it's like a reset.

Comment: you mean this one:
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY]&sensor=false&extension=.js'></script>

Comment: or is there an api key for the XML url?

Comment: changing the key didnt work. in addition, maps works perfectly when i am including coordinates by myself into the script without geocode. so it is only the xml which leads to problems. plus: the $xml->status is called before the google maps key..

Comment: @muzzie, please post another question about this with details as this is about another problem and we cannot transform this into a chat because of the rules, and give me the link. Also, when I said to change the API key I meant to create a new one, not refresh the existing one. Try creating a new project before getting the api key here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: @muzzie, you can also read here about the limits regarding this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage. It seems that you can pay to have limit set to more than 2500 requests per day. 2500 are free. Additional is 0.50$/1000 requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using **Google map api geocoding**

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600
>   Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use
>   to place markers on a map, or position the map.

Ex:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

It will return JSON or XML like:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Yes, i've been there :) but i have a long a code for my Maps plugin wich contains i.e.

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.2692714, 14.38580539999998),

.. how can those Coordinats be replaced by thos in the Link?

Comment: append your address with the above url like
address=$your_address and hit the link using curl, it will return the json or xml as response

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Geocoding API.
You need to register application in google developers console, then you can send request with your address, like 
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Universitätsring 1, 1010 Wien&key=YOUR_API_KEY`
Read this guide, it should helps. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start